# Ionic App doesn't render the youtube videos within iframe in iOS device

Tags: ios, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, youtube

The ionic app receives it's content from an external API. The content includes HTML contents with iframe to display the youtube/vimeo videos. We have made a angular directive to render the iframe content. Everything works fine in Android, but iFrame doesn't generate any content except empty Html and body tags.

Here is the generated iframe content in iOS devices,

```
<iframe ng-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A?modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;fs=0" width="400" hight="300" frameborder="0" data-srcurl="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A?modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;fs=0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bhRqrw82P3A?modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;fs=0">
 #document
 <html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using https instead of http?

Comment: yes, I tried https:// as well, but same issue.

Comment: maybe you should use $sce for secure content.

Comment: It may be issue of height and width. Put your iframe code inside body tag and give some height and width of body tag also.